# Python install local library with sub library

Tags: python

```
├── library-foo
│   ├── sub-library-bar
│   │   ├── setup.py
│   │── library things
└── setup.py
```

Now when I install the library foo I also want the library bar to install aswell. However, i'm getting the following error. I'm installing it by running

```
pip install -e ~/foo
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> bar==1.0.0 (from foo) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for bar==1.0.0

In the library foo i have a setup.py that looks like this:

```
setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1',
    description='great lib',
    install_requires=['bar==1.0.0']
)
```

in the sub library bar i have the following setup.py

```
NAME = "bar"
VERSION = "1.0.0"

REQUIRES = [
  "urllib3 >= 1.25.3",
  "python-dateutil",
]

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    author="OpenAPI Generator community",
    author_email="team@openapitools.org",
    url="",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["test", "tests"]),
    include_package_data=True
)
```